# EditText setError() with no message just the icon

Tags: android, android-edittext

Currently I have a really simple code that validates `EditText` fields and when the user hits the button at the end it checks them. It will put errors in all the fields with this:

```
if (!emailmatcher.matches()) {
    email.setError("Invalid Email");  
}
if (!zipmatcher.matches()) {
    zipcode.setError("Invalid ZipCode");                     
}
```

My problem that is the keyboard will popup and will move the error bubble to a random place. I was hoping to not have a error bubbles with a message but keep the error icons in invalid `EditText` fields. I tried inputting `setError(null)` but that doesn't work. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Your code perfect to show icon only.

As `EditText` is show anything related to when it has focused. So just change your code to like that...

```
if (!emailmatcher.matches()) {
    email.requestFocus();
    email.setError("Invalid Email");  
}
if (!zipmatcher.matches()) {
    zipcode.requestFocus();
    zipcode.setError("Invalid ZipCode");                     
}
```

Comment: bingo. `setError` indeed does not pop up the error message if the `EditText` in question is not currently focused.

Comment: @Sameer: Thanks. Now getting error messages pop up open. This works for me.

Answer (score 5):

You can use

`setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.my_error_icon, 0);`

to set the error icon to the right of your text input. You may also have to register

`View.OnKeyListener` to reset the error icon on user input:

```
EditText myEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.my_edit);

if (TextUtils.isEmpty(myEdit.getText().toString())) {
    // set the warning
    myEdit.requestFocus();

    // show error icon
    myEdit.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.error_sign, 0);

    // remove the error icon on key press
    myEdit.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            EditText eText = (EditText)v;

            // remove error sign
            eText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);

            // remove this key handler
            eText.setOnKeyListener(null);

            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me.
Now getting error messages pop up open.

```
public boolean isValid() {
        String email = ediTextEmail.getText().toString();
        String password = ediTextPassword.getText().toString();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            ediTextEmail.requestFocus();
            ediTextEmail.setError("Email cannot be blank");
            return false;
        }

        if (!isEmailValid(email)) {
            ediTextEmail.requestFocus();
            ediTextEmail.setError("Enter a valid email id");
            return false;
        }

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            ediTextPassword.requestFocus();
            ediTextPassword.setError("Password cannot be blank");
            return false;
        }

        mEmail = email;
        mPassword = password;
        return true;
    }
```

Pop opened even if my focus is on `password editText`, it will be redirected to `email editText`.

Answer (score 0):

simply create your own edittext
and override setError

```
    public class MyEditText extends EditText {

public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public void setError(CharSequence error, Drawable icon) {
    setCompoundDrawables(null, null, icon, null);
 }
}
```

and then use wherever you want
et.setError("", drawableToShow);

Comment: This is not working for me, but `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, icon, null);` seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my custom solution for popups. In this case popup is independent from EditText focus state. Moreover it is usable with multiple EditTexts.
https://plus.google.com/+AlexanderZaitsevDev/posts/W9XcZNZrsMB